# Foundation related crack assesment

Tags: foundation, brick, crack, veneer

I'm considering purchasing a home built in 1969 in a region with clay soil, where foundation settling is quite common. Looking at the exterior brick veneer, I noticed numerous cracks on 3 sides of the structure, horizontal across the full length of walls and and "stair-step" patterns in multiple places.

The slab foundation was stabilized (not repaired) two months ago with pressed pilings,  and the interior has been painted so I don't see any evidence of issues inside. My question: at what point, if any, should exterior brick veneer cracking be considered a deal-breaker?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image: Horizontal crack running length of wall]

Comment: Is this report relevant https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/171140/97780

Comment: Now we have another guess why they only stabilized the slab, from the previous question I said if stable they may not want to jack the slab because of plumbing issues, the brick would probably fail with a change of 1-1/2 , especially since some of it has been repointed. What would be a deal breaker? That will be different for everyone, today I would say unless it is a great location and buy I would not want the risk but in my 20’s I did purchase several houses fixed them up and resold them. We would need to read the engineering report if stable it could be fine. If not don’t take a chance.

Comment: @SolarMike indeed it is.

Comment: A deal breaker for me would be the bricks cracking in half. Mortar cracks easier than bricks and can be repaired, cracked bricks need to be replaced.