# Why would only part of a foundation be stabilized?

Tags: foundation

I just came across a foundation repair report, and I noticed that the area of the home that most significantly deviated (bottom left) from the reference point was the only part not stabilized. What's the rationale for such a partial stabilization? It's a 1 story home with the same ceiling height throughout, built on a slab.

[image]

Comment: Is this report relevant to this question https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/171139/97780

Comment: Without being able to read the report we can only guess. I know is some cases jacking the slab can cause plumbing issues (as in both drain and supply failures).  The report may suggest that that area is stable where the other areas were not and had to be stabilized. In some cases it is better to leave things as they are because plumbing under the slab is a pain to repair and quite costly.

Comment: @EdBeal unfortunately, the report does not mention anything relevant, only implies a successful post-stabilization plumbing test since a warranty was granted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's not Home Improvement.  This question requires professional advice that is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing the 2nd question the home is brick faced. Based on this information I believe they would not want to do any lifting as the brick work would be damaged especially in the sections that have been repointed. The assessment of the current soil conditions must be stable so no work would be needed in that area.